# Multiple Android Camera preview buffers for motion detection?

Tags: android, camera

I want to try to do motion detection by comparing consecutive camera preview frames, and I'm wondering if I'm interpreting the android docs correctly. Tell me if this is right:

If I want the camera preview to use buffers I allocate myself, I have to call addCallbackBuffer(), at least twice to get two separate buffers to compare.

Then I have to use the setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer() form of the callback so the preview will be filled in to the buffers I allocated.

Once I get to at least the 2nd callback, I can do whatever lengthy processing I like to compare the buffers, and the camera will leave me alone, not doing any more callbacks or overwriting my buffers till I return the oldest buffer back to the camera by calling allCallbackBuffer() once again (and the newest buffer will sit around unchanged for me to use in the next callback for comparison).

That last one is the one I'm least clear on. I won't get errors or anything because it ran out of buffers will I? It really will just silently drop preview frames and not do the callback?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I went and implemented the above algorithms and they actually worked, so I guess I was interpreting the docs correctly :-).

If anyone wants to see my heavily modified CameraPreview code that does this, it is on my web page at:

http://home.comcast.net/~tomhorsley/hardware/scanner/android-scanner.html